# Passing array values to command args

Tags: bash

I’m trying to write a script which executes a command to each of the elements of an array, independently of the number of values in it. However, the only solution I come up with is the following (made with the `watch` command as an example):

```
watch ${ARRAY[0]}

watch ${ARRAY[1]}

watch ${ARRAY[2]}
```

…being the array positions other commands to be watched.

Obviously, this is definitely not what I am looking for, as this depends on the number of array positions I write in my code, and that is clearly a problem. I’ve tried something like:

```
watch "${ARRAY[*]}"
```

…but it didn’t work, with or without double quotes. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should almost never use `${ARRAY[*]}`, either with or without quotes. In almost all situations, you should use `"${ARRAY[@]}"` (*with* the double-quotes) instead. Second, you should use lowercase or mixed-case variable names to avoid accidentally using a name that means something special to the shell or one of the programs you run from it.

Now, for your actual question: are you trying to run `watch` once, and pass it the full list of elements in the array, or do you want to run it separately for each element one at a time, or run a separate instance of `watch` for each element all at once? To run it once with the full list, use:

```
watch "${array[@]}"
```

To run it separately on each element one at a time, use:

```
for element in "${array[@]}"; do
    watch "$element"
done
```

To run it separately on each element sort of all at once, use `&` to avoid waiting for each `watch` command to finish before starting the next one:

```
for element in "${array[@]}"; do
    watch "$element" &
done
wait   # this waits for all of the `watch` processes to exit before continuing through the script
```